# NoneType error Problem in BeautifulSoup in python

Tags: python

im begginer at programming,  so i have problem in find method in beautifuloup when i use it in web scraping,i have this code

```
from os import execle, link, unlink, write
from typing import Text
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import csv
from itertools import zip_longest

job_titleL =[]
company_nameL=[]
location_nameL=[]
experience_inL=[]
links=[]
salary=[]
job_requirementsL=[]
date=[]
result= requests.get(f"https://wuzzuf.net/search/jobs/?a=%7B%7D&q=python&start=1")

source = result.content
soup= BeautifulSoup(source , "lxml") 

job_titles = soup.find_all("h2",{"class":"css-m604qf"} ) 

companies_names = soup.find_all("a",{"class":"css-17s97q8"})
locations_names = soup.find_all("span",{"class":"css-5wys0k"})
experience_in = soup.find_all("a", {"class":"css-5x9pm1"})
posted_new = soup.find_all("div",{"class":"css-4c4ojb"})
posted_old = soup.find_all("div",{"class":"css-do6t5g"})
posted = [*posted_new,*posted_old]
for L in range(len(job_titles)):
      job_titleL.append(job_titles[L].text)
      links.append(job_titles[L].find('a').attrs['href'])
      company_nameL.append(companies_names[L].text)
      location_nameL.append(locations_names[L].text)
      experience_inL.append(experience_in[L].text)
      date_text=posted[L].text.replace("-","").strip()
      date.append(posted[L].text)

for link in links:
      result= requests.get(link)
      source= result.content
      soup=BeautifulSoup(source,"lxml")
      requirements=soup.find("div",{"class":"css-1t5f0fr"}).ul
      requirements1=soup.find("div",{"class":"css-1t5f0fr"}).p
      respon_text=""
      if requirements:
            for li in requirements.find_all("li"):
                  print(li)
      if requirements1:
            for br in requirements1.find_all("br"):
                  print(br)
            respon_text +=li.text + "|"
            job_requirementsL.append(respon_text)

file_list=[job_titleL,company_nameL,date,location_nameL,experience_inL,links,job_requirementsL]
exported=zip_longest(*file_list)
with open('newspeard2.csv',"w") as spreadsheet:
      wr=csv.writer(spreadsheet)
      wr.writerow(["job title", "company name","date", "location", "experience in","links","job requirements"])
      wr.writerows(exported)
```

note: im not very good at english :(
so when i use find method to get the job requirements from each job in the website page (wuzzuf),use for loop to loop throug each text i job requirements, it returns error says:"NoneType objects han nod attribute find_all("li"), so after searching why this happens ,and after dowing inspect for each job page , i found that some job pages uses (br, p and strong) tags in job requirements, i didn't know what to do , but i used if statement to test it, it returns the tags but br tag is empty without text , so please can you see where is the prblem and answer me , thanks

the webpage:
https://wuzzuf.net/search/jobs/?a=hpb&q=python&start=1
the job used p and br tags:
[https://wuzzuf.net/jobs/p/T9WuTpM3Mveq-Senior-Data-Scientist-Evolvice-GmbH-Cairo-Egypt?o=28&l=sp&t=sj&a=python|search-v3|hpb](https://wuzzuf.net/jobs/p/T9WuTpM3Mveq-Senior-Data-Scientist-Evolvice-GmbH-Cairo-Egypt?o=28&l=sp&t=sj&a=python%7Csearch-v3%7Chpb)

Comment: br is always empty: it's a line BReak

Answer (score 0):

sorry i didn't understand the problem with `p` sooner

```
for link in links:
    result= requests.get(link)
    source= result.content
    soup=BeautifulSoup(source,"lxml")
    requirements_div=soup.find("div",{"class":"css-1t5f0fr"})
    respon_text=[]
      
    for child in requirements_div.children:
        if child.name=='ul':
            for li in child.find_all("li"):
                respon_text.append(li.text)
        elif child.name=='p':
            for x in child.contents:
                if x.name == 'br':
                    pass
                elif x.name == 'strong':
                    respon_text.append(x.text)
                else:
                    respon_text.append(x)
          
    job_requirementsL.append('|'.join(respon_text))
```

Comment: i need the job requirement of all pages in order to use them as csv in excel whereby each job post has its title , company name , requirements , etc

Comment: you just replace you own loop by mine

Comment: but still every job doesn't have its special requirements :|

Comment: oh sorry. as your code for p was useless i thought it was never used. my bad

Comment: ok thanks for frustration :_(